# how to get first,second ... values of two string lists inside an array list?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a problem retrieving values in the order that I want 
I wrote a simple code to demonstrate :

```
List<string> st1 = new List<string>() {"st11","st12"};
List<string> st2 = new List<string>() {"st21","st22"};
ArrayList stringArrayList = new ArrayList();
stringArrayList.Add(st1);
stringArrayList.Add(st2);

string[] n1 = new string[10];
int i = 0;
foreach (List<string> item in stringArrayList)
{
    foreach (var item2 in item)
    {
        n1[i] = item2;
        i++;
    }
}
```

in this code the output will be : st11,st12  st21,s22

i want it to get values like this : st11,st21  st12,st22

i want the information stored in this order "st11,st21  st12,st22" into n1

Comment: What would you want if the lists have different lengths?

Comment: in my case the wont have different length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the lenght of the list are the same you can make something like this:

```
int j = 0;
int lengthToLoop = st1.length;
for(int i = 0; i < lengthToLoop; i++)
{
   n1[j++] = st1[i];
   n1[j++] = st2[i];
}
```

If the length are not equal you can calculate the minimum, copy the minimum length of element from each and then copy the remaining.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that will do what you're looking for, and will also handle jagged arrays.

```
List<string> st1 = new List<string>() { "st11", "st12" };
List<string> st2 = new List<string>() { "st21", "st22",  };
ArrayList stringArrayList = new ArrayList();
stringArrayList.Add(st1);
stringArrayList.Add(st2);

//this will protect us against differing max indexes if the 2D array is jagged. 
int maxIndex = 0;
int totalElements = 0; 
foreach (List<string> currentList in stringArrayList)
{
    if (currentList.Count > maxIndex)
    {
        maxIndex = currentList.Count; 
    }
    totalElements += currentList.Count; 
 }

 string[] n1 = new string[totalElements];
 int i = 0;
 for (int j = 0; j < maxIndex; j++)
 {
     for (int k = 0; k < stringArrayList.Count; k++)
     {
         List<string> currentStringArray = (List<string>)stringArrayList[k];
         if (j < currentStringArray.Count)
         {
             n1[i] = currentStringArray[j];
             i++;
         }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check the max list length, and then take item at index (0,1,3... till max) from every list. Don't forget to check if the index exist. In addition, you can set the exact size of `n1` because it is the sum of all list count. You don't need to have a separated line for `i++` in this case.

```
        List<string> st1 = new List<string> { "st11", "st12" };
        List<string> st2 = new List<string> { "st21", "st22" };
        List<List<string>> stringArrayList = new List<List<string>> {st1, st2};
        int maxCount = stringArrayList.Max(x => x.Count);
        int totalItems = 0;
        stringArrayList.ForEach(x=> totalItems+= x.Count);
        string[] n1 = new string[totalItems];
        int i = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < maxCount; index++)
        {
            foreach (var list in stringArrayList)
            {
                if (list.Count > index)
                {
                    n1[i++] = list[index];                     
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reverse the two loops, making the outer loop the inner loop.

Use a for loop instead of a foreach loop for the outer loop using the length of the string arrays as the delimiter.

Also: Don't use ArrayList, but a real typed list.

```
List<string> st1 = new List<string>() { "st11", "st12" };
List<string> st2 = new List<string>() { "st21", "st22" };

List<List<string>> stringArrayList = new List<List<string>>();
stringArrayList.Add(st1);
stringArrayList.Add(st2);

// Get length of first string array
int firstArrayLength = stringArrayList[0].Count;

string[] n1 = new string[10];
int i = 0;

// For each position in the arrays from 0 to firstArrayLength -1 do
for (int arrayPosition = 0; arrayPosition < firstArrayLength; arrayPosition++)
{
    // For each of the string array
    foreach (var stringArray in stringArrayList)
    {
        // Get the item from the stringArray at position arrayPosition
        n1[i] = stringArray[arrayPosition];
        i++;
    }
}
```